# How to access the value from aspx page in flash?

Tags: flash, variables, ashx

Hai am trying to access the aspx variable.But i can't to do this.I dunno how to Solve my problem.anybody kindly help me.am using flash professional cs5.

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.events.Event;
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var myVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myRequest.url = "http://xxxx";
myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sendComplete);
myLoader.load(myRequest);
function sendComplete(e:Event):void{
trace(myLoader.load(myRequest));  
}
```

Comment: You need to write the ASPX variable in to the document as hidden tag maybe and then extract it by calling JavaScript inside ActionScript. Check [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Comment: can you Guide me please am new in this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code,URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT.this will retrieve the text.

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.smster.in/ipaddress/Handler.ashx"));
myTextLoader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
trace(e.target.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the ASPX variable in to the document as a hidden tag maybe and then extract it by calling JavaScript inside ActionScript. Check [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

OR, the the other easiest way is to write the aspx variable as a flash var. [Check here](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html).

OR you can use the ExternalInterface to access the query string. Check [Flash ActionScript Grab Query String Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104731/flash-actionscript-grab-query-string-value)